# How is storing data in $_SESSION different from memcache(d)?

Tags: php, session, memcached

The obvious difference is that when stored in `memcache(d)` data becomes available cross the system. Sessions store data per user, though, `session_id()` could theoretically be used to share this data with more users.

However, in terms of performance, speed and memory usage - is there a difference?

Comment: You've forgotten that _SESSION isn't in memory.

Comment: @rdlowrey, Wow. Who told you that file-system is slower than in-memory storage provided by memcache(d)? Not to mention that doesn't take into consideration whether hardware is SSD.

Comment: Everyone suggesting memcache is faster seems to be assuming a local memcache server (installed on the same machine as the application). This may be the case, when used across a network, it would be very dependent on the network.

Comment: Interesting article that helped to clear the doubts http://milancermak.posterous.com/benchmarking-tornados-sessions-0

Comment: @Guy: Memory (RAM) is always faster than HDD. Writing to the HDD (classic) is one of the most painful actions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP sessions are stored in the filesystem by default. You can modify this behaviour so that they are saved in a database, or in your case memcached.

So in terms of performance, memcached is *generally* faster than the filesystem. *This obviously depends on your environment.*

See [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)

Comment: Please share the source that tells that filesystem is slower than memcached.

Comment: @Guy obviously it depends on your hardware and load on respective hardware. *Generally* you'll find that your 7.2k RPM HDDs are slower than your memory

Comment: @Guy - do you really need a "resource" explaining that hard disk drive is slower than random access memory? If yes, feel free to check some numbers at wikipedia or compare hdds with ram. Quick facts: ram access time is measured in nanoseconds and data rate in gigabytes (32gigs is what we can get currently) while even ssd's cannot compare to that which are achieving some 500ish megabytes a sec with microseconds of seek time.

Answer (score 2):

Apples and oranges.  They achieve two entirely different things.  Your real question is file storage vs. memcache.   You could theoretically store session info in memcache instead of the file based storage.  Then the performance of session would be identical to directly pushing a value to memcache.

All things being equal, memcache performs far better than file caching.  In terms of memory, when you read the file to get the data (in this case the session file), it goes into memory anyhow, so its doesn't save any space.  In fact if multiple requests happen to apache different worker process may need to read the same session file--each using their own chunk of memory until the worker process is reaped.  Using memcache, this doesn't happen.

---

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply use memcache for `$_SESSION`. That's definitely faster, as it doesn't require a lot of calls to a PHP API, but it goes straight to the C API instead.

Small performance bonus though, PHP really isn't all that slow.

If you're going to compare memcache with filesystem sessions: use memcache. Really, you should, as that simply stores them in memory instead of storing them on the filesystem. A lot faster. Of course, you do risk losing session data if the memcache server overloads. Memory usage of memcache will of course be higher than the filesystem alternative.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but aren't PHP API's / Extensions created in C?

Comment: Yes, they are, but if you want to use raw memcache functions to store the session instead of the `$_SESSION` replacement, it'll be slightly slower, as PHP will have to interpret and lookup every function call you make.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are stored in either a file or database. Memcache is stored in memory for faster access.